# Invoking functions in other kernels

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization, resource-management

Suppose one wants to parallelize as much as possible N tasks, each task produces a graphics via `ParametricPlot` or something like that. If the system is allowed to run 4 parallel kernels, how do I assign the tasks to all the available kernels?

So far what I've been doing is opening multiple notebooks, each running on a separate kernel, and running on different batches of input data.

Is there a better approach for this? Is possible to spawn a clone of the current kernel, or possibly just invoke code to execute in other kernels, so that the master program runs inside a single notebook, but schedules commands to other kernels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ParallelDo` and `ParallelTable` to parallelize automatically.

```
ParallelTable[
    ParametricPlot[p, ...],
    {p, {thingsToPlot}}
]
```

Depending on your case, you could use `Export` inside of `ParallelDo` to save the files as you go. Otherwise the results will be returned to the master kernel if you use ParallelTable.

Comment: `ParallelDo` sounds exactly what I need. Thanks

Comment: You should be aware of some problems that may occure when using ParallelDo when writing to shared variable. ParallelTable handles this without additional programming effort, so you get back a "clean" list with all the elements in the right order. ParallelDo may have issue when trying to write an entry to a list while a second kernel is also doing so (see CriticalSection). In addition you may get a messed up order with ParallelDo depending on wich kernel finishes first. So there is no relation of list order and index order unless you store the index with the result.